# Plotting QDA projections in R

Tags: r, discriminant-analysis

When doing discriminant analysis using LDA or PCA it is straightforward to plot the projections of the data points by using the two strongest factors.

This can be done in R by using the x component of the pca object or the x component of the prediction lda object.

My question is: Is it possible to project points in 2D using the QDA transformation?

If yes, how would we do this in R and ggplot2?

Comment: Unlike LDA, quadratic discriminant analysis (QDA) is not a linear method, meaning that it does not operate on [linear] projections.

Comment: Then there is no way to visualize the separation of classes produced by QDA?

Comment: I don't know what is the best approach. But you can to try to project data to 2D with some other method (like PCA or LDA) and then plot the QDA decision boundaries (those will be parabolas) there. Try [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=qda+discriminant+decision+boundary&tbm=isch) for some examples. Update: these examples mostly run QDA already in 2D, as far as I can see...

Comment: [This](http://ramhiser.com/2013/07/02/a-brief-look-at-mixture-discriminant-analysis/) article seems to do a similar thing.

Answer (score 3):

The only tool I found so far is `partimat` from `klaR` package. It's not the same as plotting projections in PCA or LDA. But it can give you an idea about the separating surface.

Example:

```
library(klaR)
partimat(Species ~ ., data = iris, method = "qda", plot.matrix = TRUE, col.correct='green', col.wrong='red')
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you! I noticed that it is a good idea to run twice the code. The second time using plot.matrix = FALSE.